# Android SQLite interaction best practice

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it OK to have `SQLite` interactions on UI thread ??
Is it a best practice to embed interactions with SQLite within a service(`AsyncTask` or `IntentService`) or should we  use `CursorLoader` for `SQLite`??

1)If I use `IntentService` to return a list of user defined objects then how do I that. Should we use `BroadcastReciever` and put the list of objects in intent as `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` objects and send it back to UI thread.

2)If I have to use cursor Loaders then I need to write custom loader for `SQLite` by extending `AsyncTaskLoader` and override  `doInBackGround` method where I add required code.

Please suggest me which is better approach as I am new to android and also share the code if anybody has it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can access database on UI thread & update views straightaway.
One should avoid this practice & do database access on helper threads i.e. use asynctasks/services with worker threads even if operation is taking less than 5 seconds. You can always use non-UI to UI thread communication mechanisms in android for updating views once thread is done with it's job.

Refer this link to learn basics about non-UI to UI thread communication mechanisms. http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-non-ui-to-ui-thread-communications-part-1-of-5/

I normally use AsyncTasks created on activity/service for DB access.
If android later decides to disallow DB access on UI thread, then your code will not need rework if DB access already on non-UI thread.

There is history with android that network access was earlier allowed on UI thread, but now if you set targetSDKversion=11, then application will throw NetworkOnMainThreadException & exit.
Hence, it is better to DB access on non-UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i had a question which one is better AsyncTask or IntentService..as you use AsyncTask will it not get affected if the orientation changes.

Comment: I don't think you can compare network access with accessing the internal database. Network access never was meant to run on the UI thread, it's just that since version 11 it explicitly checked that it does not. As for database access -- queries that take 5 seconds are rather rare. Just storing an entry or updating a field normally takes just milliseconds, so mosten times it is not worth the overhead of involving a different thread.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to use SQLite on the UI Thread. There is no need to add all that service and parable stuff, except perhaps if you intend to scroll through huge amounts of data.

Comment: when using a `ListView` with a `CursorAdapter` there is really no difference if you have "huge" amount of data or just few hundreds of rows

Comment: Thanks, i spent whole lot of time trying to use intent service and then also tried using SQLiteCursorLoader but found it hard to implement.